# sfrac inside siunitx no longer works

Tags: siunitx, xfrac

I have been using `\sfrac` inside of `siunitx` for a long time.  Since recently, it does not work and I get bunch of errors.  Can you suggest me what to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,xfrac}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\sfrac{1}{2}}

\begin{document}

\si[per-mode=fraction]{\W\s\rooted\per\m\squared\per\K}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/558 went to CTAN yesterday to allow `\sfrac` as the fraction function. This one is more complicated: powers really should be real numbers (as they might need to be summed, etc.).

Comment: @JosephWright This is theoretically square root of a second, so 1/2 is more appropriate than 0.5.  I did not completely understand your comment.  Is this going to be fixed?

Comment: I meant that the timing was 'interesting'. In terms of a fix, I have been meaning to cover conversion of decimals to fractions, but not just at the moment. I'll think about the specifics of this case, and see if there is a possible way to handle it. (I note that in a superscript, `\sfrac{1}{2}` is _very_ similar to `1/2`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises due to some internal handling of `\text`. As a work around, you can use

```latex
\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\text{\sfrac{1}{2}}}
```

which should keep your document working.

---

The issue itself is complex. In v2, `siunitx` resets all text and math mode font settings for each number/unit. That's quite 'expensive' when most of the time only math or text is needed. So for v3 I only set the math mode font with we are in math mode. That leaves needing to handle `\text` nested in math mode. To cover that, I apply the `siunitx` font settings if `\text` is found in math mode. However, `\sfrac` internally uses `\text` around each box, and that causes the issue here. I have handled it for the case `fraction-command = \sfrac`, but it's less clear how to do that for an arbitrary `\sfrac` nested inside math mode.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Please, if you ever implement a solution that does not require using `\text`, please leave the message here or provide new answer.

Comment: I have just realised that your `\text` mode works well in when units in fraction mode, but when units in inline mode it looks completely disorted (huge slash).  Any other workarounds?

Comment: @Pygmalion Please ask a linked question with an example

Comment: I just realised that this is a problem of `newtx`, which makes `sfrac` really ugly.  Nothing to do with siunitx.

Comment: The link to new question for reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634865/ugly-sfrac-with-newtx