# Ugly sfrac with newtx

Tags: typography, newtx, xfrac

I am using `\sfrac` with the `newtx` font package, and I get a very ugly result:

[image]

WHat I am doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\sfrac{$1$}{$2$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `$\sfrac{1}{2}$` instead?  Old Style Figures (OSF) are not really intended for use in math constructs.  In any event, I cannot reproduce your output.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is better, but I need `\sfrac{$1$}{$2$}`, because I have to use it in `siunitx`, command `\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\text{\sfrac{1}{2}}}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623172/sfrac-inside-siunitx-no-longer-works/623261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `\usepackage{fix-cm}` to remove the font warnings, and make sure you have the `cm-super` collection installed (it is installed by default in texlive but apparently not in miktex)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\begin{document}

\sfrac{$1$}{$2$}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to adjust the positioning specify the xfrac  template parameters for this font family (there are lots, but this is a start)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{ntxtosf}{text}
{
   numerator-top-sep = .1em,
   denominator-bot-sep = -.1em,
   slash-right-kern = -.06em,
   slash-left-kern = -.06em
}

\begin{document}

\sfrac{$1$}{$2$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, the slash itself is not a major problem, the biggest problem is that numbers are so far away from the slash.

Comment: @Pygmalion that's probably just the nested math. you didn't say what you disliked I was so horrified by the pixelated slash in your image I didn't consider anything else

Comment: If I turn off `osf` and remove `$$`, I still get the same spacing problem.

Comment: @Pygmalion see update

Comment: @Pygmalion the spacing is font dependent and there is no way how xfrac could know what to do for each and every font (it knows for some but ...).  So if you have  "ugly outcome" you need to tell xfrac what it should use instead according to your taste. David now provided an example, but the documentation contains more details on how to set up  instances